# Find delta for epsilon

Tags: limits

Given $\epsilon$ $>$ $0$ find $\delta$ $>$ $0$ such that $\sqrt{t^{2}-1} < \epsilon$ when $\left | t-1 \right |< \delta$    i tried to factor $t^{2}-1$ as $\sqrt{(t-1)(t+1)}$  but how do i get rid of the square root problem

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: implicitly, you must have $\lvert t\rvert\geq 1$, otherwise the square root is not defined.*

If $\lvert t-1\rvert < \delta$, then

- $\lvert t\rvert < 1+\delta$, so that $\sqrt{\lvert t\rvert+1} < \sqrt{2+\delta}$
- $\sqrt{\lvert t-1\rvert} < \sqrt{\delta}$

and therefore, from your factorization,
$$
\sqrt{t^2-1} < \sqrt{2+\delta}\cdot \sqrt{\delta}.
$$
It then only suffices to find some $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon)$ so that
$\sqrt{2+\delta}\cdot \sqrt{\delta}\leq \varepsilon$.

**Tip:** you can enforce $\delta \leq 1$ if you want (since you get to "find" *any* right $\delta(\varepsilon)$), in which case you can solve $\sqrt{3}\cdot \sqrt{\delta}\leq \varepsilon$ instead, as long as the solution is $\leq 1$. This is simpler.

Comment: What if $t=-2$? I guess you mean to require $|t|\geq1$, not just $t\geq 1$. Of course, if $t$ is sufficiently close to $1$, your condition will do.

Comment: My bad. Indeed, this should be $\lvert t\rvert$, in all generality.